# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: ethers.js

Im getting this error when i try to create an eventListener

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

This is my eventListiner

```
const AddNewEvent = (eventFilter, provider, cb) => {
    provider.removeListener(eventFilter);
    console.log('Event filter',eventFilter);
    provider.on(eventFilter, (logs) => {
        const parsedLog = new ethers.utils.Interface(ABI).parseLog(logs);
        console.log('Parse log', parsedLog);
        cb(parsedLog);
    });
};
  

export const createEventListener = ({ navigate, contract, provider, walletAddress, setAlert, setUpdateGameData }) => {
    const NewPlayerEventFilter = contract.filters.NewPlayer();
    AddNewEvent(NewPlayerEventFilter, provider, ({ args }) => {
        console.log('New Player created!', args);
        if(walletAddress === args.owner){
            setAlert({
                status : true,
                type : 'success',
                message : 'Player has been successfully registered!'
            });
        }
    });

    const NewBattleEventFilter = contract.filters.NewBattle();
    AddNewEvent(NewBattleEventFilter, provider, ({ args }) => {
        console.log('New battle started!', args, walletAddress);
  
        if (walletAddress.toLowerCase() === args.player1.toLowerCase() || walletAddress.toLowerCase() === args.player2.toLowerCase()) {
            navigate(`/battle/${args.battleName}`);
        }
  
        setUpdateGameData((prevUpdateGameData) => prevUpdateGameData + 1);
    });

}
```

This is my useEffect where i initilaze the eventListiner

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if(contract){
        console.log('Contract', contract);
        createEventListener ({
            navigate, contract, provider,
            walletAddress, setAlert,
            setUpdateGameData
        })
    }

}, [contract]);
```